# Laravel property [filename] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

When I edit product, I'm trying to edit multiple images also, so if I upload new images the old images should be replaced by the new ones but now if I upload images I'm getting an error `Property [filename] does not exist on this collection instance."` and the old images are not deleted but the new images have been added. There are products and ProductsPhoto tables that are related, in ProductsPhoto table there is a filename column, and product_id column. How can I replace the old images with the new ones when editing a product?

My code.

Blade template

```
 <input multiple="multiple" name="photos[]" type="file">
```

Controller

```
 public function update(Request $request)
{
 $product = Product::with('ProductsPhoto')->find($request->product_id,'id');

  if ($request->hasFile('photos')){
        //Add the new photo
        foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {
            $filename = $photo->store('public/photos');
            ProductsPhoto::create([
                'product_id' => $product->id,
                'filename' => $filename
            ]);
        } 
        $oldFilename = $product->ProductsPhoto->filename;
        //Update the database
         $product->ProductsPhoto->filename = $filename;

         //Delete old photo
         Storage::delete($oldFilename);
    }

     $product->save();
  }
```

Comment: Does your ProductsPhoto model have "filename" as a $fillable property on the model? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent #massAssignment section

Comment: Yeah it does have filename as fillable ,@SweetChillyPhilly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that a **product** hasMany **productsPhoto**, so `$product->ProductsPhoto` is a collection, and not a photo!

I don't know how your entities are defined, especially **Product** and **ProductPhoto** classes:
But you should delete the old collection of **productsPhoto**

`$product->productsPhoto()->delete();`

and save the new ones:

```php
$newPhotos=[];
foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {
    $filename = $photo->store('public/photos');
    $newPhotos[] = new ProductsPhoto(['filename'=>$filename]);
} 
$product->productsPhoto()->saveMany($newPhotos);
```

Rather than trying to replace file names

Comment: I'm getting this `"Undefined variable: newPhotos"` and the old photos have been deleted but it can't add new ones @jcHache

Comment: `$newPhotos` was a reference to your new photos (an array)
You have to create them in your foreach

Comment: How can I create that? @jcHache

Comment: I updated my post, just for the example, but without any guarantee that it will work since you didn't put the code of the models